# ASP.NET Core 5.0 : how to exclude runtimes folder for system.IO.Ports package

Tags: c#

I have a nuget package `System.IO.Ports` and select build platform "Any CPU". After compiling, the "Runtimes" for any platform libraries (ARM, OSX etc.) is generated in the output directory.

Just use the X86 or X64 library. Please how to set up a project for inclusion only one dll file?

Comment: You could delete the unused ones, but I wouldn't. Just leave the build system do its job. If you start messing around with the build output, you're likely getting into much bigger trouble than a bit of extra disk space used.

Comment: When publishing your asp.net application, there is a "Produce Single File" option which will output a clean .exe file anyway. It doesn't remove the unwanted files, but at least it hides them for the final user.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

For other OS versions you can use conditions like this:

```
<CurrentRuntimeId Condition="'$(CurrentRuntimeId)' == '' AND '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">win7-x64</CurrentRuntimeId>
<CurrentRuntimeId Condition="'$(CurrentRuntimeId)' == '' AND '$(OS)' == 'Unix'">linux-x64</CurrentRuntimeId>
<RuntimeIdentifier>$(CurrentRuntimeId)</RuntimeIdentifier>
```